# Find the Cramer Rao lower bound given the following distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_n$ be independent and identical with the distribution:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}(1+\sin[\pi(\frac{x-\theta}{2\Delta})]) & \text{if $\theta -\Delta<x<\theta +\Delta$} \\ 1 & \text{if $\theta +\Delta<x<\theta -\Delta+1$}  \\ \frac{1}{2}(1-\sin[\pi(\frac{x-\theta-1}{2\Delta})]) & \text{if $\theta -\Delta+1<x<\theta +\Delta$+1} \\ 0 & \text{if $otherwise$}   \end{cases}$$

The problem asks to find the Cramer-Rao lower bound on the variance of any unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

I know that the lower bound of any unbiased estimator $T(x)$ is:

$$\frac{1}{nE[(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}log\space\ f(X|\theta))^2]}$$

The trouble I'm having is how to apply the above distribution to the lower bound equation. I'm not sure how to take the expectation of a piece wise density like that.  Any suggestions towards the right direction to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using $E\left[\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\log{f(X|\theta)}\right)\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\theta\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\log{f(X|\theta)}\right) d\theta}$? Shouldn't be too hard with piece wise integration, and two of the pieces are simple.